# React-Native - this.props is undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have problem in my application. I triy navigate to next page, but I get this Error:
TypeError: _this3.props.navigate is not a function. (In 'this3.props.navigate' is undefined)

Really I checked my this.props with a console.log and the result is undefined.
In others components I have props populated and navigate normally.
I tryed construtor whithout argumet props too.

What Happening?

```
export default class GuidedMeditation extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          search: '',
          isLoading: true,
          dataSource: []
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {

        api.get('api/v1/meditations-instructor') 
            .then(response => this.setState(
                {dataSource: response, isLoading: false}
                ))
            .catch(error => this.setState({error, isLoading: false}));
        }



    render() {
        console.log('props: ' + JSON.stringify(this.props));
        return (
            <Body style={styleProperties.bodyMeditation}>

                <View style={styleProperties.meditationCard}>
                    <ScrollView>
                    <FlatList
                        data={this.state.dataSource.data}
                        renderItem={({ item }) =>


                    <Card bordered style={styleProperties.meditationCard} >

                        <CardItem button onPress={() => this.props.navigate('MeditationPlayer')}>
                            <Left>
                                <Thumbnail square large source={{uri: 'https://loremflickr.com/50/50/love?random='+item.id}} />
                                <Body>
                                    <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                                    <Text note>{item.instructor_first_name == null ? '' : item.instructor_first_name +" "+item.instructor_last_name}</Text>
                                </Body>
                            </Left>
                        </CardItem>
                        <CardItem button onPress={() => alert("This is Card Header")}>
                            <Text>{item.meditation_description}</Text> 
                        </CardItem>
                    </Card>

                } keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id} />

                    </ScrollView>

            </View>
        </Body>

        );
    }
}
```

The call

```
  <Button vertical
                                    style={{
                                        backgroundColor: this.state.selectedTab === 'guidedMeditation' ? '#41b25a' : undefined,
                                    }}
                                    active={this.state.selectedTab === 'guidedMeditation'}
                                    onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: 'guidedMeditation', showSearch: 'true'})}
                            >
                                <Icon name="list"/>
                                <Text>Meditação</Text>
                            </Button>
```

Comment: Please specify Where GuidedMeditation is defined or called?

Comment: Here 
<Button vertical active={this.state.selectedTab === 'guidedMeditation'}
      onPress={() => this.setState({selectedTab: 'guidedMeditation', showSearch: 'true'})}
                            >
             <Icon name="list"/>
             <Text>Meditação</Text>
     </Button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should be

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(...)
```

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.